# Shared partial view uses always same controller even though it is rendered via another controller's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a shared partial view which consist of a form. This partial view is shared between two different controller. Let's call them `Controller1` and `Controller2`. The problem is, whether I am using the `Controller1`'s `Insert` view or `Controller2`'s `Insert` view, the action method `Insert` of `Controller1` is always being called.

Let's say I am filling the form at the `localhost:58888/Controller2/Insert` and then push the submit button, in this situation the `Insert` action of `Controller1` is operated and debugger never reached to `Controller2`'s `Insert` method. After a summary of my problem, I would like to share with you some of my code.

Here is the shared partial view;

```
@model TabNetMVC.Models.EOrder.Product
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group" lang="tr">
                @Html.Label("Ürün Adı", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name,
                        new List<SelectListItem> {
                            new SelectListItem {
                               Text="Test-1",
                               Value="1",
                            },
                            new SelectListItem {
                               Text="Test-2",
                               Value="2",
                            },
                        }, "Kategori Seçiniz", new { @class = "form-control", id = "itemDropDown" })
                    <p style="display: none; color: red;" id="dropdownValidation">Lütfen Ürün Seçiniz!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" lang="tr">
                @Html.Label("Miktar", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 text-left" })
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Quantity, new { @class = "form-control", id = "itemQuantity" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessage("Quantity", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    <p style="display: none; color: red;" id="quantityValidation">Lütfen Miktar Seçiniz!</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-4">
                    <button class="btn btn-success col-lg-4" type="submit" id="btnAdd" onclick="return Validation(@((int)Enums.MissingItem.Add))"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here, `Product` model which is used at this shared view is a base class of both of other two models which is being used by `Controller1` and `Controller2`. I tried to make us of polymorphism to make this shared view as generic as possible.

Lastly, I am sharing two different action method of each Controller.

**Controller1's Insert method;**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Insert(MissingProduct product)
        {

            if (SessionHelper.Products == null)
            {
                SessionHelper.Products = new List<Product>();
            }

            if(product.Statu == (int)Enums.MissingItem.SendConfirm)
            {
                //Operations for inserting into database placed here...
                SessionHelper.Products = new List<Product>();
            }
            else if (product.Statu == (int)Enums.MissingItem.Add && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SessionHelper.Products.Add(product);
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/EOrder/ItemListControl.cshtml");
        }
```

**Controller 2's Insert method;**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Insert(SupplementaryProduct product)
        {

            if (SessionHelper.Products == null)
            {
                SessionHelper.Products = new List<Product>();
            }

            if (product.Statu == (int)Enums.MissingItem.SendConfirm)
            {
                //Operations for inserting into database placed here...
                SessionHelper.Products = new List<Product>();
            }
            else if (product.Statu == (int)Enums.MissingItem.Add && ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                SessionHelper.Products.Add(product);
            }

            return PartialView("~/Views/EOrder/ItemListControl.cshtml");
        }
```

As you see, both of action methods are almost identical except the data type is `MissingProduct` at `Controller1`'s Insert method and `SupplementaryProduct` at the `Controller2`'s Insert method. Lastly note that, both of the `Insert` action has its own view which renders this shared partial view into itself.

What can be causing this? Thanks in advance...

Comment: That would depend on hw your form is being submitted. Can you show how the form is declared?

Comment: The form declaration is into shared partial view. There are no other implementation logic in other file for submitting the form.

Comment: Sure, but my point is, when you delcare a form, you tell it which URL to submit itself to. And I suspect this is where the problem is, it is somehow declared to always submit to Controller1. To confirm that, we would need to see how you declare that form (supposedly with `<form>` or `Html.BeginForm`, neither of which i see right now)

Comment: @Andrei, You catched the point! I was always redirecting to same controller via my `Ajax.BeginForm`. You can post it as answer and I will mark it. Thanks!

Comment: glad it helped! answer posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an issue with the form definition. When you define a form, you tell it which URL to submit itself to. And I suspect this is where the problem is, it is somehow declared to always submit to `Controller1`.

So in your shared view check the declaration of the form, either with `<form>` or with `Html.BeginForm` or with `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Ozan. can you expose and checks the action attribute value of the form in the shared partial view?

```
...<form ... action='/Controller1/Insert' ...>
```

In many cases this causes the extrange behavior.

Please checks any html helper that renders your form code ...

Thanks